# Pulling git changeset logs previous to clone

Tags: git, grep

I'm using 
`git log --grep="searchstring"` to peruse the past several years of changesets on my local repository, but my search results only return matching changesets created after my clone. How do I either:

1: pull the remaining logs to search through,

or alternatively

2: search for keywords in the remote repository's log/changeset descriptions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot get the remote log without fetching the actual history with Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get results from your entire log using `git log --grep="searchstring"`, and if you created your local repository using a normal `clone` you probably have all log messages from the upstream repository.

1. If you just run `git log`, do the messages that you aren't able to grep for show up? You may find it convenient to search through the paged log results with `/searchstring`. You can use `n` to go to the next match, and `q` to quit.
2. By default, `git log` only shows results from the active branch. You may find that adding `--all` to your command will help. This affects both your original command and the regular log I mentioned above.
3. Finally, are there any remote branches that you are not tracking? Log messages in these branches will not show up until you fetch them.

Comment: This helped reveal the real issue, which is that there's a 9 month chunk of missing changesets in the remote repository. It may have happened when we migrated from mercurial to git. I don't know, but since this helped me diagnose it, I'm going to mark it as the answer.